# Unable to Import/Export types from a custom mdule?

Tags: typescript, npm, node-modules, typescript-typings

I'm working on a typescript module (as part of a larger monorepo) and I can't seem to import types from one package in to another (via node modules). My types are built to `./types` and my package.json as a `types: types/index.d.ts` key in it. For whatever reason, I can't seem to import the types in to another module, when developing locally.

It seems as though it should just *work* and that npm/typescript would resolve these appropriately.

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./types"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error - I'd redefined the library in `global.d.ts` in the project...